# How a shared service can be updated by a deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

In the Kubernetes docs, in the [Using Labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#using-labels) section it says:

> A Service can be made to span multiple Deployments by omitting release-specific labels from its selector. When you need to update a running service without downtime, use a Deployment.

I don't understand how this can be achieved by a Deployment? When we want to update a service shouldn't it happen separately (on its own), separate from any Deployments? Like:

```sh
kubectl apply -f service.yaml
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A service points to a set of endpoints (pods) determined by its label selector.

Let's take an example of a service that has the label selector

```yaml
app: api
version: v1
```

It will point to all pods that have these two labels (may have more).

If you deploy a new version, with label `version: v2` the existing service will NOT point to these pods since the label selector no longer matches the pods labels.

On the other hand, if you omit `version: v1` from the label selector of the service and leave only `app: api`, the service will point to any pod that has the `app: api` label, meaning when you deploy a new version, even if the version label has a new value, the service will still point to these pods.

This way you can update the service pods without updating the service itself - you can do that only by deploying your new api version.